# No route Match then redirect to home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

In my routes I added this two routes

```
match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))', :controller => /admin\/[^\/]+/

match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
```

When I goes to invalid route then giving me

```
The action 'dashboard1' could not be found for Admin::AdminController
```

I added below line at the end of the routes.rb file

```
match "*path" => redirect("/")
```

But it's not working.

I am using rails 3.2.x

Please Help me, Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

wouldn't the two routes catch everything that is in controller/action format?

I guess you are doing everything in admin controller or redirecting to proper controllers and actions, by parsing the params in the admin, redirection to home page should be done in the controller where you are doing that, perhaps a begin rescue block?

```
begin
  ....rerouting logic
rescue
 redirect_to home_page
end
```

of course you should check if the exception is the correct one and so forth.